# RK 4 simultaneous method

Tags: numerical-calculus

Help with using the Runge-Kutta 4th order simultaneous method on a system of 12 first order ODE's.
i have 12 ODE and want to solve them using RK simultaneous method.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.